# Panel afterRender using loader config

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a panel which I create and it has the loader config in it to load a jsp page into it. The jsp has markup in it which I need to attach a listener to in my ext controller. The issue I'm having is I listen to the afterrender on the panel, but the dom from the jsp page hasn't always been render/loaded yet its a timing issue(sometime the afterrender can find the dom other times it can't at this point). I tried putting a listener on the loader to listen for load. But again I have the same issue sometimes the dom has been rendered at that point and some times it hasn't (again its a timing issue).

```
Ext.create('panel', {
  listeners : {
       afterrender: {
           fn : function(){
               Ext.dom.Query.select('#mydiv');//sometimes this finds it some times it doesn't
           }
       }
    }
  loader : {
   url : '/my/jsp',
   autoLoad : true,
   listeners : {
       load : {
           fn : function(){
               Ext.dom.Query.select('#mydiv');//sometimes this finds it some times it doesn't
           }
       }
    }
}
});
```

Is there an event to listen to after the jsp is loaded and the dom is render in the panel? I think afterrender is being called before the loader is done loading the jsp's dom into the panel and the same with the loader load event. I need to make sure the dom from the jsp is render in the panel before I attempt to query the dom and attach the listener.

Comment: Have you ever found a reliable solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the delay option in the listener http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.EventManager-method-addListener 
It's not a full proof method but could work for you.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but it felt like a hack. I may use that as a temporary fix for now.

Comment: This is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The loader fires a load event, so you can listen to it using:

```
component.getLoader().on('load', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: I did try that it I get the same issue. Still doesn't always work since the DOM isn't always rendered at that point.